# Can the Domino HTTP task serve content from another Domino server?

Tags: http, ibm-domino

Is there any way or trick to open some database resource that resides on ServerB by sending the request to the HTTP task running on ServerA?

Of course, both servers are in the same org, and have proper access rights...

Comment: This is not about redirection. My question is about asking the HTTP task on ServerA to connect to ServerB over NRPC, read some content, and return it directly to the requestor, without redirecting to ServerB (which might not have the HTTP task running).

Comment: I have no answer, but rather just wanted to comment that 1) I had no idea that Domino was actually still a thing and 2) I am *so* sorry you have to deal with it.

Comment: @EEAA, I believe Domino is very good. I've tried other different technologies, and I still feel that working with Domino & Notes is a good investment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a db link on ServerA that points to the db on ServerB works fine.

From the Domino Administrator this is not possible. So, on ServerA create a text file in the data directory (or a sub directory of that), fill it up with `ServerB/Domain!!Path\DBName.nsf` and rename it to `mydbname.nsf`.

Now when `http://ServerA/mydbname.nsf` is requested, `Path\DBName.nsf` will get served from ServerB over NRPC to ServerA, then HTTP will hand it to the browser.

Comment: Of course! Great solution.